# Sql Server 2008 "Contains" search searching for numeric value returns all records with a different number of the same length?

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains, full-text-indexing

I have a search where users can enter any value, sometimes these are legitimately just numeric.
When searching for

```
Select * FROM Updates WHERE contains(Remarks, '"10010234331"')
```

it will return unrelated results that have numbers in of the same length, ie one match for the above is

```
"PO input differently on orders, refs are: 

1001024894 
10010248940"
```

As you can see, the search is not a substring of either of these. Any ideas how to tell it to not just guess?

Comment: Can you not use `like`?

Comment: We are searching a text field with full-text indexing, the volume of records to be searched means that using like is unworkably slow.

Answer (score 0):

Right.

As unbelievable as this sounds, it turns out that if the full-text index "language for word-breaker" is set to anything other than "English", the full-text index will only index the first 5 numbers of a number string.
This means that the above is returning as a match because they both start "10010".

"French, "German", "Hebrew", even "Neutral" was returning incorrect results, only "English" returns only matches for the whole string.

```
create table wtFTI( taskid int not null  ,  remarks text, constraint   [PK__wtFTI] primary key(taskid))
insert into wtfti
values(3513792, 'Remarks: 1001019658  was cancelled 26/08')
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [TaskRemarks]WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF

GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[wtFTI] KEY INDEX [PK__wtFTI] ON ([TaskRemarks]) WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[wtFTI] ADD ([remarks]LANGUAGE 'French')
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[wtFTI] ENABLE
GO


Select * FROM [wtFTI] WHERE contains(Remarks, '"1001019000"')

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[wtFTI] DROP ([remarks]) 
GO
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[wtFTI] ADD ([remarks] LANGUAGE 'English')
GO


Select * FROM [wtFTI] WHERE contains(Remarks, '"1001019000"')
```